# Why was my spam flag declined for this answer?

Tags: support, declined-flags, spam

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36648680/3942918) as spam because it:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

The answer exists only to promote an IBM product, the [author's profile indicates they work for IBM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4454969/valerielampkin), there is no disclosure of this in the answer.

It was declined with:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

---

The question itself was closed with:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as **they tend to attract** opinionated answers and **spam**...

*(Emphasis mine.)*

Does the fact that the question is likely to attract spam mean that the spam it attracts is somehow no longer spam? The spam flag description says nothing about promotion being specifically unsolicited.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: She is a member of the [bluemix] team at IBM.  Somewhat like the anti-Google, the team supports their product and projects at SO by actively answering questions.  Almost all of the top-users in that tag are team members, I stopped counting at 12, and identify themselves as such in their profile.  Jon Skeet does not identify himself as a Google employee every time he answers a [java] question.  Or Eric Lippert as a (former) Microsoft employee for [c#].  Etcetera, plenty of precedent.  Is is okay to hate the answer, but it as usual fits the excessively poor and off topic question.

Comment: @HansPassant In this case the user is suggesting the use of a product, in such a case the answer *would* require disclosure of affiliation, in the same way that Jon will disclose when he recommends a 3rd party tool that he (or his company) has worked on.  No disclosure that  you're employed by the company creating the language the question is asking about is necessary, per the rules, it's just needed when suggesting a product or tool.

Comment: The question is poor enough for her to have no idea that is what *not* about [bluemix] support.  Feel free to assume that IBM instructs its employees to intentionally spam SO, you didn't bring enough evidence to convince me however.

Comment: Probably because the problem wasn't that answer, it was the question.  The answer was correct and, while lacking the nicety of a disclaimer about being a team member, it provided the question with what it specifically asked for--spam.  And questions that ask for spam should be nuked from orbit.  You shouldn't have bothered flagging the answers, you should have downvoted, vtc, and then voted to delete the question.  I do, however, firmly believe in downvoting answers to off topic questions, so you could have done that as well.

Comment: Well, the big part of spam that makes it spam is that it's not asked for.  If I want to take a cruise, and I go into the cruse ship convention hall and yell out "which one of you cruise-y bastards wants my filthy money?" they're all going to mob me and start pitching me for their lines.  I asked for it.  Now, if I'm sitting on my toilet playing candy crush and I get a text from some cruise line saying I won a free trip when I despise cruise ships and never entered any stinking contest for no legionnaires-infested vomit bucket, *that's spam*.

Comment: *And that's why the problem was with the question!!* Ha ha!  I'm super glad you now understand!  Congratulations, good sir, and now I must bid you a good day!

Comment: @PaulCrovella The problem with the answer was that it didn't disclose the affiliation, not that it recommended a product.  That's a very different problem than if that same answer were to be posted to hundreds of randomly chosen questions for which the product in no way solved the problem.  That would be spam, not just a fixable problem with a legitimate (but low quality) answer.  Such a problem isn't handled with the "spam" flag.

Comment: Can some >10k user post an image of the answer, for <10k.

Comment: @PaulCrovella There clearly the whole Q/A pair is spam. It's an entirely different situation, and you knew that.

Comment: But intentions *aren't* irrelivant.  There's a *huge* difference between a sincere answer to a sincere question that happens to involve suggesting a product and an account created purely to advertise a product, to the point that the rules describe exactly that difference when discussing spam.

Comment: That's not actually what I said at all, but if you don't want to handle spam appropriately, you'll have to accept the consequences.  If it's too hard for you to understand, that's fine, perhaps reviewing isn't for you.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Not all low quality content is spam.  If you can't distinguish between spam and other types of low quality content, and use the moderation tools appropriately, then you're going to have flags declined and other similar consequences.  There's *lots* of information in the help center and elsewhere on meta on spam, if you really want to learn more, but it seems that you're not actually interested in learning how to moderate appropriate, or actually learning what you did wrong.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Then you've learned exactly the wrong lessons, and are only going to continue to improperly flag content in the future.  That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 55):

Spam would be for *unsolicited* promotion of a product or service.  Posting an answer to a question suggesting the use of a product *when that product answers the question being asked* isn't spam.  In this case, the question is actually a product request, so that it is getting product recommendations as answers is by design.  Of course, such questions are not appropriate here, so the *whole question* merits deletion, but not as spam (and the additional consequences that entails).

You are correct that that answerer should have disclosed their affiliation, but as the answer is otherwise an appropriate answer in context, it would simply merit the post being edited, not deleted as spam.  Had you used a custom mod flag to indicate that the author didn't disclose their affiliation based on their profile, a moderator would have been able to address that problem appropriately.

Comment: Based on what you've stated above, then doesn't [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768399/how-does-mq-light-assure-that-message-is-not-removed-from-queue-if-app-crashes-d) deserve similar treatment? She's a member of the Team that writes the software - shouldn't she know the answer to the question she's asking?

Comment: @Paul how do you know she's a "a member of the Team that writes the software" rather than she is just using those products?

Comment: @BillWoodger: Wouldn't she just ask the question internally, rather than on a site like SO?  I know that when we write software in our organisation the first people we ask about specific issues or queries regarding a product are the authors... Also, I read her profile: *IBM employee currently working in Internet of Things, Message Hub and MQ Light for Bluemix Cloud services, previously WebSphere MQ administrator/troubleshooter.*

Comment: "working in" not "working on". Traditionally there would be internal places to ask within IBM. I have no idea if that avenue (presuming it exists) has been exhausted before asking here. Traditionally IBM employees were not allowed to ask questions publicly. There are IBM's own public Developerworks areas. However, those get much less traffic than SO does. All I come to is "I don't know what specifically she works on" for sure, but things tend to be pointing at "doing stuff for clients, using these products". Given that, I was curious how you could be so sure.

Answer (score 14):

If the only reason you spam flagged the answer is because it did not disclose the affiliation, then IMHO it was rightly rejected.  A one-off, no-disclosure-given answer by a user in good standing should not merit a spam flag.  Instead, you should comment to them, and explain the error of their ways.  At most it deserves a custom mod flag with an explanation of why you believe it is spam.  Remember that a spam flag is very heavy and includes a -100 rep penalty.  To me, that is too harsh for a first time offense, when we could instead just educate the user via comments.

If we follow the link on the spam flag, bullet point one states:

> **Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much.** Folks will read your answers for their ability to solve a specific problem; if you're good at doing that, then they'll find themselves more interested in who you are and what you're working on. If you respond only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling, they'll assume you're just here to sell.

Here the **too much** means it is *okay* to do this, but don't do it *often*.  If this is their only answer where they suggest this product, then they are following that guidance.  It is easy for a user to forget that they need to have the disclosure *in the answer* even when they have it on their profile.

Comment: In general, this is why I declined the flag. Spam flags can carry severe penalties, and I didn't want to impose that on someone who had otherwise been a productive member of the site. I do handle longstanding accounts who happen to slip up and forget attribution differently from brand-new accounts whose first post is to advertise a commercial offering. Perhaps I should have disputed, rather than declined the flag, since I understand the intent of the flag. I just didn't want to penalize a helpful member of IBM's support team who provided a targeted answer to a question asking for resources.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for commenting.  I figured that was the case and I have been told a few times by SO mods and Staff that we should always give users in good standing the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @PaulCrovella: It's not. The description is "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation." Much of this fits, except the "only" part. The answer also answered the question. It was not unsolicited. It was not spam.

Comment: @PaulCrovella: Special case (that admittedly I didn't mention) - the question itself was posted with the sole purpose of providing a home for the spam answer.